# Getting Unexpected HTTP status code: 403 in Gitlab

Tags: visual-studio, gitlab

I am getting an `Unexpected HTTP status code: 403` error in Gitlab. I can push codes to `gitlab` from a windows machine. When I try to update the solution in a Mac visual studio I am getting the above error message. I am the creator of the project and my username and password are correct. Is there any way to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still, I have same issue when update and commit changes from Mac VS. So now I am using `Terminal` in Mac to update and commit new changes. It works the same as `Git CMD` and we can use the same `GIT CMD` commands on `Terminal`. But when revert changes using `Terminal` Xaml file changes not reverted to old one. No other issue found on Mac Terminal.